# How to join multiple quires in single with date range And populate it individually

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fetch data from multiple tables in a single query, And display all data from one table first by giving a heading of related table name, and at footer sum of score for every table.
As I tried in my code its working good but I want it do in a single query.

How can I do this in single query and fetch one table data first with table name header and sum of score at footer, And so on for every sport.

```
?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$startDate = $_POST['fromDate'];
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $startDate);
$start_date = $date->format("Y-m-d");

$endDate = $_POST['toDate'];
$format = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $endDate);
$end_date = $format->format("Y-m-d");

$query = $db->prepare("SELECT DATE(dateby) AS date, score FROM cricket_table WHERE dateby BETWEEN :st_date  AND :en_date ");
$query->bindParam(':st_date', $start_date);
$query->bindParam(':en_date', $end_date);
$query->execute();

if ($query->rowCount() > 0)
    {

    echo '<label>Cricket</label>
          <table>
          <tbody>';
    $total = 0;
    while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $row['date']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['score']; ?></td>
                            </tr>   

<?php
        $total += $row['score'];
        }
?>      
                      </tbody>  
                         <tfoot align="right">
                            <tr><th></th><th></th><th><?php echo $total; ?></th></tr>
                        </tfoot>
                  </table>

<?php
 }
$query1 = $db->prepare("SELECT DATE(dateby) AS date, score FROM football-table WHERE dateby BETWEEN :str_date  AND :ending_date ");
$query1->bindParam(':str_date', $start_date);
$query1->bindParam(':ending_date', $end_date);
$query1->execute();

if ($query->rowCount() > 0)
    {

    echo '<label>Football</label>
          <table>
          <tbody>';
    $total1 = 0;
    while ($row1 = $query1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $row1['date']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row1['score']; ?></td>
                            </tr>   

<?php
        $total1 += $row1['score'];
        }
?>      
                      </tbody>  
                         <tfoot align="right">
                            <tr><th></th><th></th><th><?php echo $total1; ?></th></tr>
                        </tfoot>
                  </table>
    <?php
    }
} ?>
```

**Update**

Its now working with one query and one HTML table, But now the issue is total, its not getting correct sum for every table, should be one total for every sports.

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT 'cricket' sport
 , DATE(dateby) date
 , score 
  FROM cricket_table 
  WHERE dateby BETWEEN :st_date  AND :en_date
UNION ALL
SELECT 'football'
 , DATE(dateby) date
 , score 
  FROM football_table 
 WHERE dateby BETWEEN :str_date  AND :ending_date");
$query->bindparam(':str_date', $str_date);
$query->bindparam(':ending_date', $ending_date);
$query->execute; 
$total=0;
                $norepeat = null;
                while($row = $query->fetch(PDO:: FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
                      $sport = $row['sport'];
                      $date = $row['dates'];
                      $score = $row['score'];
                      $total += $score;

                     if ($norepeat != $sport) {  
                        echo"<h1> $sport </h1>";
                          $norepeat = $sport;
                      }
            echo '<table">
                      <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td>'.$date.'</td>
                            <td>'.$score.'</td>
                           </tr>
                     </tbody>  
                     <tfoot align="right">
                        <tr><th></th><th></th><th>'.$total.'</th></tr>
                     </tfoot>
                </table>';
                 }
```

Comment: Never include arithmetic operators in table/column identifiers. As written, the above query could not possibly be 'working', so there's something you're not telling us

Comment: @Strawberry The question  was not submitting without this. Because it was asking more and more explanation.

Comment: So you want to merge data from two tables and then split it again. But why?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I want to display the table name to its related data as heading. And  sum of the score at the footer for every table data.

Comment: So just don't merge them. Why everyone wants to do anything with only one query?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel because there will be bunch of code, If I use multiple 8 or 9 queries, and its related while loop data, it will be difficult to handle.

Comment: Let me guess: You have 8 tables (one for each sport) and they all look the same (have the same columns)?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel yes 8 table but not fully the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my point of view your code is fine but if you still want to do it in single query then you can achieve it by using some logic in php.

here is @Strawberry 's query.

```
SELECT 'cricket' sport
     , DATE(dateby) date
     , score 
  FROM cricket_table 
 WHERE dateby BETWEEN :st_date  AND :en_date
 UNION ALL
SELECT 'football'
     , DATE(dateby) date
     , score 
  FROM football_table 
 WHERE dateby BETWEEN :str_date  AND :ending_date
```

and here is php code:

```
if ($query->rowCount() > 0)
    {
        $isNewSport=""; //check if is new entry exits
        $total=0; //for sum to score. you can also total score by using a subquery in sql
        while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            if($row['sport']==$isNewSport){ //check if this is old sport/record
                echo '<tr>
                        <td>'.$row['date'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['score'].'</td>
                     </tr>'
                ?>
                <?php
                $total+=$row['score']; //addition to score row by row
            }
            if($row['sport']!=$isNewSport){ //check if column has new sport/record if so create a new html table or close the last table  
                if($isNewSport!=""){ //if this is new sport so last sport html table should be close
                    echo '</tbody>  
                         <tfoot align="right">
                            <tr><th></th><th></th><th>'.$total.'</th></tr>
                        </tfoot>
                        </table>';
                    $total=0; //and new sum should be zero      
                 }
                 //if this is new sport then new html table should be created.
                echo '<label>'.$row['sport'].'</label>
                      <table>
                      <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td>'.$row['date'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['score'].'</td>
                       </tr>';
                    $total+=$row['score'];
                    $isNewSport=$row['sport']; //after creating 1st html then set it is as old sport.
            continue;
            }
            echo '</tbody>  
                <tfoot align="right">
                    <tr><th></th><th></th><th>'.$total.'</th></tr>
                </tfoot>
                </table>';
                //at then end close last html table and print total socre
            }
 }
```

I haven't checked it yet but you can add more tables in query.
Please let me know if you have any questtion.

Comment: Its now working with one query and one HTML table, But now the issue is total, its not getting correct sum for every sport, should be one total for every sport. As you can see in the update

Comment: @Eniol did you run my example ? If so can you upload screenshot of output?

Comment: @Eniol you can use 2 subqueries one for each table score for total score if you are unable to do it in php. eg: (SELECT sum(score)
  FROM cricket_table 
 WHERE dateby BETWEEN stdate and enddate) as total,

Comment: chalo ok ye mai javascript mai karlonga.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a valid query:

```
SELECT 'cricket' sport
     , DATE(dateby) date
     , score 
  FROM cricket_table 
 WHERE dateby BETWEEN :st_date  AND :en_date
 UNION ALL
SELECT 'football'
     , DATE(dateby) date
     , score 
  FROM football_table 
 WHERE dateby BETWEEN :str_date  AND :ending_date
```

Comment: And how can I populate every table data in a different HTML table?

Comment: It's just a simple loop. Every time 'sport' changes, you start a new table.

Comment: this way it fetches sports name for every row. But I want to fetch 1 sport name and total of score for every  particular database table.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a redesign of the database having all common sport attributes in a single table. Then a single query solution would be much simpler. But with one table per sport, I wouldn't try to solve the task with a single query, unless I have an evidence of a significant performance issue. Since the task is the same for every sport and only differs in the name, you can use the same code in a loop.

```
// set $start_date and $end_date

$sports = [
    'Cricket'  => 'cricket_table',
    'Football' => 'football_table',
    // more sports
];

foreach ($sports as $sportName => $tableName) {
    $query = $db->prepare("
        SELECT DATE(dateby) AS date, score
        FROM `{$tableName}`
        WHERE dateby BETWEEN :st_date  AND :en_date 
    ");
    $query->execute(['st_date' => $start_date, 'en_date' => $end_date]);
    if ($query->rowCount() > 0) {
        echo "<label>{$sportName}</label><table><tbody>";
        $totalScore = 0;
        while ($row = $query->fetchObject()) {
            echo "<tr><td>{$row->date}</td><td>{$row->score}</td></tr>";
            $totalScore += $row->score;
        }
        echo '</tbody><tfoot align="right">';
        echo "<tr><th></th><th>{$totalScore}</th></tr>";
        echo '</tfoot></table>';
}
```